# Error: Sending email using PHP

Tags: php

I had an error with the sending of an e-mail with php, because I have an smtp server name call smtp.office365.com, how should I try?

```
<?php
    require "PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php";//Am I correctly include thelibraries?
    require "PHPmailer/src/smtp.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); >I get an error
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host='smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->Port=25;
    $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
    $mail->Username='username';//What username have I had to type?
    $mail->Password='password';//The password is above office365 email?
    $mail->SetFrom('sender_email', 'FromEmail');
    $mail->addAddress('destination', 'ToEmail');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject='Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body= 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';  
    ?>
```

> I get an error, because when I try to execute It on a server Linux It won't send the email and It gave me a 'HTTP ERROR 500'

Comment: Please I need an help!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you read its documentation: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Can you give me an help?

Comment: Becasue I've copy It on my server and It  doesn't run

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4

Comment: Yes I've already read It, but I can't find a solutions @KenWhite

Comment: First check whether you have included libraries correctly or not? Debug the code line by line(using echo & exit). And find exactly which line is causing error.

Comment: Yes the libraries is included correctly, the line which take me an error is that: $mail = new PHPMailer(true); @LovepreetSingh

Comment: Try as: $mail = new \PHPMailer(true);

Comment: It doesn't work :( @LovepreetSingh

Comment: Do I have to add this: require_once "Mail.php";   ?

Comment: office365 requires TLS usage.

Comment: What does It mean? Do I have to include something other? @bradbury9

Comment: first of all its not a good idea to include files one by one, find the autoloader file inside your library and include that file only. Yyou dont need require "PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php";//Am I correctly include thelibraries?
    require "PHPmailer/src/smtp.php"; file to import manually. For example `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";` or require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php'; and try to catch the eception, enable error reporting too

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Host=smtp.office365.com
$mail->Port=587
$mail->Username=XXXXXXX
$mail->Password=XXXXXXX
$mail->Encryption=tls
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't work on $mail because when I declare It  It give me an error

Comment: try to fetch this all variable from environment file

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
require "PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPmailer/src/smtp.php";    
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for 365
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->Port = 25; 
        $mail->Username = 'username';  
        $mail->Password = "password";           
        $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
```

Comment: I'm on live, what should I do?

Comment: The problem is always $mail=new PHPMailer()